# Send additional data with data table ajax server side

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, datatables

my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.all').dataTable( {
        "bInfo": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, 100], [25, 50, 75, 100]],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Get_Pmob_tra",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<img src='gfx/ajax-loader.gif'>"
        }
    } );
} );

</script>
```

and I am using datatable class to process the  files

I need to get a new value from html to the PHP with an ajax call

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fnServerParams](http://datatables.net/ref#fnServerParams), like this:

```
...
"sAjaxSource": "Get_Pmob_tra",
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "myval", "value": $('#myselect :selected').val() });
},
"bPaginate": true,
...
```

This example gets the selected value of a selectlist with the id='myselect', and passes it as a parameter called 'myval'. In your server-side Get_Pmob_tra php code, get the parameter from the request:

```
Request.QueryString["myval"]
```

sorry that's not specifically PHP code, but you get the idea.